# Regression with convnet on image using keras - accuracy can't increase more than 40%

Tags: python, tensorflow, image-processing, keras, regression

The whole problem to solve is to read the number that these energy meters are showing. [An Image of the energy meter.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eq9IU.jpg)
And then I need to be able to implement all of it in an android application.
What I am trying to do is to first by regression find the location of the black rectangle which contains the number. Then try to read the numbers by another network.

1- Have I chosen the right path to this problem?

2- What is wrong with my network below?

I have a small dataset of 78 images like the one above.
For predicting the location of the rectangle I cropped some small images out of the original ones with sliding 500*200 size window. And I've got almost 10,000 images of size 500*200. With the first versions of the network, I was getting high accuracy and low loss. But the problem was that I was getting the exam same output for any input. I tried different things and retrained but there was no luck. but this last network has no accuracy.

This is how i'm loading the data:

```
def load_train_data(self):
       data = np.empty((0, 20, 50, 1), int)
       labels = np.empty((0, 8), int)
       files = glob.glob(self.dataset_path + '\\train\\*.jpg')
       print('{} train files found'.format(len(files)))
       print('loading files...')
       for i in range(len(files)):
           image = Image.open(files[i]).convert('L')
           data = np.append(data, [np.array(image).reshape((20, 50, 1)).astype('float32') / 255], axis=0)
           labels = np.append(labels, [np.array(self.decode_file_name(files[i]))], axis=0)
       return (data, labels)

def decode_file_name(self, file_name):
       arr = file_name.split('\\')
       name = arr[len(arr) - 1];
       name_parts = name[0:len(name) - 4].split("_")
       if len(name_parts) == 11:
           temp = [int(name_parts[3]), int(name_parts[4]), int(name_parts[5]), int(name_parts[6]),
                int(name_parts[7]), int(name_parts[8]), int(name_parts[9]), int(name_parts[10])]
       else:
           temp = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

       return temp
```

This is the model:

```
def build_model():
     m = tf.keras.Sequential([
        tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, kernel_size=10, activation=tf.keras.activations.relu, input_shape=(20, 50, 1),
                           data_format='channels_last'),
        tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, kernel_size=5, activation=tf.keras.activations.relu),
        tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(100, activation=tf.keras.activations.relu),
        # tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(8, activation=tf.keras.activations.linear)
     ])

     m.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.0001), loss=tf.keras.losses.mean_absolute_percentage_error,
          metrics=['accuracy'])
     return m
```

And then finally the fit function:

```
model = build_model()
history = model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=10, validation_data=(x_test, y_test))
```

This is the result of the above network:

[Accuracy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kLNaU.png)

[Loss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zVIVN.png)

## UPDATE

I found a bug in the process of loading the dataset and fixed it. I retrained the network but no matter how I change the network, accuracy stays below 40%.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Here's an approach using OpenCV to obtain the ROI of the black rectangle

- Convert image to grayscale and Gaussian Blur
- Canny edge detection
- Perform morphological operations to smooth image
- Find contours and filter using a minimum threshold area
- Create mask with desired rectangle
- Extract ROI

---

Canny edge detection

[image]

Morph close

[image]

Find contours and filter using a minimum threshold area to isolate rectangle then draw onto a mask

[image]

From here, we find the bounding rectangle and then extract using Numpy slicing

[image]

Result

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

image = cv2.imread('1.jpg')
result = image.copy()
mask = np.zeros(result.shape, dtype=np.uint8)
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(image, (3,3), 0)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(blur, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
canny = cv2.Canny(gray, 120, 255, 1)
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (3,3))
close = cv2.morphologyEx(canny, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)

cnts = cv2.findContours(close, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]

min_area = 10000
for c in cnts:
    area = cv2.contourArea(c)
    if area > min_area:
        cv2.drawContours(mask, [c], -1, (255,255,255), -1)

mask = cv2.cvtColor(mask, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
result[mask==0] = (255,255,255)

mask_canny = cv2.Canny(result, 120, 255, 1)
cnts = cv2.findContours(mask_canny, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]

for c in cnts:
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
    ROI = result[y:y+h, x:x+w]
    cv2.imwrite("ROI.png", ROI)
    cv2.rectangle(result, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (36,255,12), 2)

cv2.imshow('canny', canny)
cv2.imshow('close', close)
cv2.imshow('image', image)
cv2.imshow('mask', mask)
cv2.imshow('result', result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: First, I need to be able to implement the same thing in android. Second, this doesn't work when there are multiple black boxes in the image.

Comment: You should add that the goal is to run the program on android to the original post. It should work with multiple boxes, just need to save the ROI as different images

Comment: I did edit the post and added the goal of running on android. Are these features of cv available on android two??

Comment: I'm not familiar with android but I believe there is an OpenCV library for android. You can follow the steps but implement it in android

Comment: Thank you, and what do you suggest for reading the numbers after extracting the black box??

Answer (score 0):

I think that this approach is not the best way to solve the problem. I would instead capture pictures of different energy levels and label each image as such, so that you have for example 500 images of what each energy level looks like on the meter. This would train the network to look at the rectangle when determining the energy level. The sliding window approach is unnecessary since your goal is for the network to learn what to look for instead of telling it what to look for in the image, such as the location of the rectangle. Hope that helps.

Data augmentation can also be used to artificially increase the size of your dataset.

https://medium.com/@thimblot/data-augmentation-boost-your-image-dataset-with-few-lines-of-python-155c2dc1baec

Comment: The dataset is limited. And the image shot angle can differ, so I think that can't be done. Right?

Comment: Then, I would suggest using Data Augmentation to translate, rotate and blur your pictures to artificially generate more data. I'll link an article in the answer

Comment: Each meter shows a 6 digit number. If I try to solve it as a classification problem then I'll at least need 10^6 images of the meter without consideration of shot angle.

Comment: Oh I have an idea. I look at the picture and noticed that there are specific characters on the meter. You should train a network to look at the characters and interpret the reading, but that would require you to crop the image that you've provided down to just the meter.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm trying to do. I should first find the black rectangle then read the numbers individually.

Answer (score 0):

It would be a better strategy to use OpenCV to locate and crop the black box first and then use deep learning to predict the value in the box.

but to get better results, you can also crop the digits of the meter individually with OpenCV. After that you can easily detect the values using a DNN similar to MNIST.

Comment: But how can I use OpenCV to locate the black rectangle?

Comment: https://cvisiondemy.com/extract-roi-from-image-with-python-and-opencv/

this shows a way to do it on textual images. But your case is different.
May be you can use blob detection along with the above tutorial
https://www.learnopencv.com/blob-detection-using-opencv-python-c/